# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' to 'NSArray'

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var TableViewOutlet: UITableView!

 let URL_GET_DATA = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.500010,78.461527&radius=1000&types=atm&key=AIzaSyA4G66cD6FTzU1UnLO2UHL2rpehzDNa2v4"

 var icons = [Icon]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in


        if let json = response.result.value {

            let iconArray : NSArray  = json as! NSArray

            for i in 0..<iconArray.count{

                self.icons.append(Icon(
                    name: (iconArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String,
                    imageUrl: (iconArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "imageUrl") as! String
                ))
            }

            self.TableViewOutlet.reloadData()
        }

    }

    self.TableViewOutlet.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return icons.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "one", for: indexPath)as? TableViewCell

    let icon: Icon
    icon = icons[indexPath.row]

    cell?.nameOutlet.text = icon.name

    Alamofire.request(icon.imageUrl).responseImage { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let image = response.result.value {
            cell?.ImageOutlet.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell!
}
```

}

**I am getting an error like this**

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10a439508) to 'NSArray' (0x10a439008).
>   2018-09-27 17:42:43.020278+0530 TableViewJSON[14887:1123768] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10a439508) to 'NSArray' (0x10a439008).

And at line 30 I got an error saying

> Thread1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: `response.result.value` is `dictionary` and BTW what is line 30?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to be format your code properly and when you refer to some error message at some line, it would be wise to indicate where is that in the code with some comment line. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: let iconArray : NSArray  = json as! NSArray : this is line 30

Comment: `json as! NSArray` there's your problem... json is not an array. Why are you  attempting using NSArray for Swift? Swift has it's own bridged classes so you rarely need to use anything prefixed with NS (with some exceptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: `json` is a dictionary (`[String:Any]`), not an array. Don't use `NSArray` – as well as horrible `as AnyObject).value(forKey:` – in Swift at all!

And always conditional bind the value to avoid crashes

```
...
   if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any], // <- Swift Dictionary
      let results = json["results"] as? [[String:Any]]  { // <- Swift Array

      for result in results {
          print(result["name"] as! String)
      }
```

There is no key `imageURL` in the JSON at all

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Actually I am unable to display icon image on TableView. Can you suggest me how can I do it

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Actually I am unable to display icon image on TableView. Can you suggest me how can I do it.  And imageUrl is not a key in Json but it is as String that I specified in another class and I specified it as 
class Icon {
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: String
    
    init(name: String, imageUrl: String){
    self.name = name
    self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }
}